Flutter Androiud find which package uses FOREGROUND SERVICE
Google Play store wants to know, where I use FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION. But I have absolutely no idea.
When running grep -nr "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" this was the output:

./build/app/intermediates/merged_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml:53:    
./build/app/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml:53:    
./build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:53:    
./build/app/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/release/manifest-merger-blame-release-report.txt:101:53    
Binary file ./build/app/intermediates/intermediary_bundle/release/shrinkBundleReleaseResources/intermediary-bundle.aab matches
Binary file ./build/app/intermediates/intermediary_bundle/release/packageReleaseBundle/intermediary-bundle.aab matches
./build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:53:    
./build/app/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-release-report.txt:1294:uses-permission#android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION

Any idea or way, how I can find out where exactly I am using it ? I'm quite lost here.

Maybe grep in ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev ? I guess it will show packages which are have this manifest entry. Next, you will compare this list and your pubspec.lock.

@Sameri11 no result :/

Once you build the app you can check the manifest merger report at
 <project-root>/build/app/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-release-report.txt

Simply open the file and search for the permission say FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
You will find something like this
..
...
android:name
        ADDED from [:stream_video_flutter] /.../.../Documents/Projects/.../build/stream_video_flutter/intermediates/merged_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml:10:22-85
uses-permission#android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
...
..


For foreground services, use 'background_services' library.
To add this package to your project, include it in your pubspec.yaml file:
flutter_foreground_service: ^0.2.0

instead of
flutter_background_service: ^5.0.5

And then, add this line in 'AndroidManifest.xml' file.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION"/>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
